# assigning static var to non-static var, method to return the values not working

Tags: php, static-variables

I'm new to PHP and practicing using static variables. I decided to grab an example that I learnt from C++ and re-write it for PHP (example from the bottom of [this article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/)).

There's a class with two private variables (one static), a constructor and a get-method. The constructor assigns the static variable's value to the second private variable, and then increments.

```
<?php
class Something
{
    private static $s_nIDGenerator = 1;
    private $m_nID;

    public function Something() { 
       $m_nID = self::$s_nIDGenerator++;
       echo "m_nID: " . $m_nID . "</br>"; //for testing, can comment this out
    }
    public function GetID() {
        return $m_nID;
    }

}

// extra question:
// static variable can be assigned a value outside the class in C++, why not in PHP?
// Something::$s_nIDGenerator = 1; 

    $cFirst = new Something();
    $cSecond = new Something();
    $cThird = new Something();

    echo $cFirst->GetID() . "</br>";
    echo $cSecond->GetID() . "</br>";
    echo $cThird->GetID() . "</br>";
?>
```

Using the echo test in line 9 to see if m_nID is getting a value I see:

```
m_nID: 1
m_nID: 2
m_nID: 3
```

But these values are **not** being returned by the "->GetID()" calls. Any ideas why?

*Edit: both replies so far have solved this, I wish I could "check" them both, so thank you! I'll leave the original code in the question as-is for any future people who have a similar problem*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your background in C++ led up to this issue, which is an easy mistake to make. In PHP, all instance (or object) variables are referenced using `$this->`, and static (or class) variables with `self::`. Based on your code:

```
public function GetID() {
    return $m_nID;
}
```

Access to the private variable `$m_nID` should be scoped like this:

```
public function GetID() {
    return $this->m_nID;
}
```

And inside your constructor:

```
$m_nID = self::$s_nIDGenerator++;
```

It should have been:

```
$this->m_nID = self::$s_nIDGenerator++;
```

**Q & A**

> Why is there no need to put `$` before `m_nID` when using `$this->`

The above two ways of referencing instance and class variables come with a very different kind of syntax:

1. `$this` is the instance reference variable and any properties are accessed using the `->` operator; the `$` is not repeated for the property names themselves, although they're present in the *declaration* (e.g. `private $myprop`).
2. `self::` is synonymous to `Something::` (the class name itself); it doesn't reference an instance variable and therefore has no `$` in front of it. To differentiate static variables from class constants (`self::MYCONST`) and class methods (`self::myMethod()`) it's prefixed with a `$`.

**Extra**

That said, `$this->$myvar` is accepted too and works like this:

```
private $foo = 'hello world';

function test()
{
    $myvar = 'foo';
    echo $this->$foo; // echoes 'hello world'
}
```

Comment: I checked the above reply by Mr. Cook where he suggested using `$this->` in the constructor as well as the get-method, which worked --- but thanks for your help too! and yes while I'm aware of `this` in C++, I find I'm needing to use it more learning PHP

Comment: Just saw that now, thanks! And if I may (if you see this) -- why is there no need to put "$" before "m_nID" when using `$self->`?

Comment: @tempe Doing that would mean something else ... let me add that in the answer as well, because this space is too short for that.

Comment: @tempe Okay, done editing my longish second update :) let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been a great help. Coming from C++ I understand some of the OO concepts but the syntax changes and lack of declarations (although C++11 uses auto now :P) has taken getting used to. Thanks again!

Comment: @tempe Well, coming from C++ you may know more about OOP than the average PHP dev ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Something{
    private static $s_nIDGenerator = 1;
    private $m_nID;

    public function Something() { 
       $this->m_nID = self::$s_nIDGenerator++;
    }
    public function GetID() {
        return $this->m_nID;
    }

}
```

It is interesting to note the difference between using `self::$s_nIDGenerator` on a static variable vs using `$this->s_nIDGenerator` on a static variable, whereas `$this->` will not store anything.

Comment: thank you for your reply, however using `$this->` leads to an error that reads:`Cannot access empty property` --- which seems to imply that `$m_nID` is empty, when I know it shouldn't be (as shown in my echo test on line 9)

Comment: which line is it saying "Cannot access empty property", I just tested, and received no errors.

Comment: ahhh nevermind I accidentally kept the "$" beside both m_nID's (i.e. `$this->$m_nID`), which caused an error to appear, using your code worked - thank you!

Comment: +1. Your answer didn't miss the wrong reference in the constructor, unlike mine before ;-)